# Download bootstrap with CSS files not the LESS files

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Why does bootstrap now only have LESS files and not the usual bootstrap.css file? Is there a link to download the bootstrap framework with the CSS files and not the LESS files?

Comment: are you talking about this website ?? http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just download the latest version from the [Bootstrap Website](http://getbootstrap.com/), extract it and look inside the */dist/css* folder like you can see on their [GitHub Project](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/dist/css).